# Creando una contraseña con condiciones en c#

Tags: c#, string, condiciones, vscode, booleano

Necesito ayuda con la creación de una contraseña con condiciones donde le pregunte al usuario que cree una contraseña de al menos 7 caracteres y no más de 12, que tenga al menos una letra mayúscula y al menos una minúscula, un número y el símbolo!,

Traté de crear el código declarando las condiciones en strings y luego creando un boolean para verificar si la contraseña introducida cumplía con los requisitos, pero no funciona, aquí lo que tengo hasta ahora :

```
using System;

namespace new_test_lab
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {            
            var upperCase = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
            var lowerCase = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
            var numbers = "0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ";
            var Simbol = "!";

            Console.Write("Welcome, please create a password for your secret recipe where the following criteria must be met: \nYour password must contain: \nAt least one lower case letter \nAt least one uppercase letter \nAt least minimun 7 charaters \nAt least maximum 12 charater \nAn exclamation point : ! \n\nPlease enter your password here:  ");
        
            string Password = Console.ReadLine();

            int MaxAndMin= Password.Length;           
            bool firstCheck = Password.Contains (upperCase);
            bool secondCheck = Password.Contains(lowerCase);
            bool thirdCheck = Password.Contains(numbers);
            bool FourthcCheck = Password.Contains(Simbol);

            if (firstCheck && secondCheck && thirdCheck && FourthcCheck && MaxAndMin >= 7 && MaxAndMin <= 12)
            {
                Console.WriteLine( " Password valid and accepted");
            } 
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error");               
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string clave = Console.ReadLine();
bool debil = false;

if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(clave))
{
   debil = (!Regex.IsMatch(clave, @"([a-z])")) ? true : debil;

   debil = (!Regex.IsMatch(clave, @"([A-Z])")) ? true : debil;

   debil = (!Regex.IsMatch(clave, @"([0-9])")) ? true : debil;

   debil = (!clave.Contains("!")) ? true : debil;

   debil = (clave.Length < 7) ? true : debil;
}     
else
{
   debil = true;
}  

if(debil)
{
   //Imprimo clave débil
}
else
{
   //Imprimo clave fuerte
}
```

Se declara la **variable debil** que es la que nos va a indicar si nuestra clave cumple con los requisitos de fortaleza que les definimos, en este caso verificamos que la clave no está vacía, posteriormente comprobamos a través de **expresiones regulares** si la clave está compuesta por minúsculas, mayúscula, números y si tiene una longitud mayor o igual a **7**, también se verifica que esté el símbolo **"!"**, en caso de no cumplirse las condiciones anteriores se considera que la clave es débil.

Para usar las **expresiones regulares** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, lo voy a intentar, soy nuevo en c# y coding and general, tu ayuda es agradecida.

Comment: Ok, el código funciona yo lo uso en mis cosas, si la respuesta te sirve por favor marcarla como aceptada, gracias y cualquier duda me escribes para aclararte, un saludo

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya trate el codigo y la mayor parte funciona, solo que siempre me imprime que es debil aunque cumpla con los requisitos, esta todo tal cual lo pusiste y agrege el using pero aun asi me imprime debil aunque sea fuerte

Comment: Dime algunas de las contraseñas con las que has probado

Comment: Acuérdate que si no se cumple al menos alguna de las condiciones se considera débil, aunque se cumplan todas las demás, basta con que no se cumpla una

Comment: Gracias, lo pude arreglar, me falto agregar un signo de exclamación. Gracias por la ayuda